# Display Div Overlay on :hover with CSS3 Ease-In Transitions

Tags: html, css, animation

I've got the overlay working on :hover. However I'd like to add an ease-in transition using CSS3. Can't seem to find a working version online.

To the code!

So I have a div which contains just an image. When I hover over it, it displays a coloured overlay with 2 text elements.

```
<div class="item">
     <img src="assets/images/blah.jpg" class="image">
         <a class="overlay" href="#">
            <h3 class="title">Some title</h3>
            <div class="description">
              <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. consectetur adipisicing elit.</h4>
            </div>
         </a>
</div>
```

For my CSS, I have added the -transition code:

```
.item {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease-in; 
  transition: background-color 2s ease-in; 
}

.overlay {
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
 }

.item:hover .overlay{
   display:block;
   background-color: black;
}
```

However this transition effect it isn't working! Please help!

Do I need to change the -transition to use `display` or `all` ?

I have a [jsfiddle which has the :hover working](https://jsfiddle.net/jonahmclachlan/nwhzLu1g/2/), just without the animation.

Much appreciated

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/jonahmclachlan/nwhzLu1g/2/

Comment: `display` is not a transitionable property. You are changing it from `none` to `block` on hover and so it will never transition.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6943704/4334348

Comment: Thanks guys! That's making sense. I thought display: block was killing it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must to change the display with an opacity for example, and add the transition to the overlay, not the item.

See it working:

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
}

.overlay {
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease-in, opacity 2s ease-in; 
  transition: background-color 2s ease-in, opacity 2s ease-in; 
 }

.item:hover .overlay{
   background-color: black;
   opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease-in, opacity 2s ease-in; 
  transition: background-color 2s ease-in, opacity 2s ease-in; 
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
     <img src="assets/images/blah.jpg" class="image">
         <a class="overlay" href="#">
            <h3 class="title">Some title</h3>
            <div class="description">
              <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. consectetur adipisicing elit.</h4>
            </div>
         </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Marcos, why do I need to declare the -transitions twice?

Comment: The first is to make the transition on mouse leave, and the second is to make the transition on mouseover. IF you remove the first transition, you'll see the transition only on hover, but not when you leave the mouse over.

Comment: Ah yeah in and out - that looks better actually.

Comment: Maybe you want to add `visibility: hidden` where after was `display:none`, to avoid the hover on the overlay.

Comment: @Xsmael yes it's running

Comment: Alright, yes it is, but the image link is broken and i didnt even try...